# Traversing back to parent and go to all its child element with ($this)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to add classes on my anchor links based on how far the user has scrolled, using Jquery. I was able to add class but it wont be removed using `removeClass`. I'm sure the problem is the selectors im using in jquery. Do i need to traverse back and add specific selectors from parent element instead of assigning directly the `removeClass` on my anchor links.

Instead of adding classes to the list elements, I'd rather apply the classes to the anchor links itself which is my personal choice.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#first">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#second">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#third">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="home" style="height:1000px; background-color:red;"></div>
<div class="about-me" id="first" style="height:1000px; background-color:green;"></div>
<div class="portfolio" id="second" style="height:1000px; background-color:blue;"></div>
<div class="contact" id="third" style="height:1000px; background-color:orange;"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .active {
  color:gray;
  }
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var scrollLink = $('.scroll');

scrollLink.click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 1000)
})

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollLoc = $(this).scrollTop();

    scrollLink.each(function(){

        var traverse = $(this.hash).offset().top - 20;

        if (traverse <= scrollLoc){
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    })
})

})
```

I expect that classes from other anchor links would be removed when they are not shown on screen.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53957448/2630817

Comment: I'd personally remove the class from all the elements and then add it to the one that is relevant, but @KevinKoobs below has given a clean alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust your condition to have a lower and upper bound. Since your elements has the same height it should be easy.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scrollLink = $('.scroll');

  scrollLink.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 1000)
  })

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollLoc = $(this).scrollTop();

    scrollLink.each(function() {

      var traverse = $(this.hash).offset().top - 20;

      if (traverse <= scrollLoc && traverse + 1000 >= scrollLoc ) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
    })
  })

});
```

```css
.active {
  color: gray;
}

ul {
  position: fixed;
  background:#fff;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#first">About Me</a></li>
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#second">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#third">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="home" style="height:1000px; background-color:red;"></div>
<div class="about-me" id="first" style="height:1000px; background-color:green;"></div>
<div class="portfolio" id="second" style="height:1000px; background-color:blue;"></div>
<div class="contact" id="third" style="height:1000px; background-color:orange;"></div>
```

In case height is not the same you can do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scrollLink = $('.scroll');

  scrollLink.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 1000)
  })

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollLoc = $(this).scrollTop();

    scrollLink.each(function() {

      var traverse = $(this.hash).offset().top - 20;
      var traverse_up = $(this.hash).offset().top - 20 + $(this.hash).height();

      if (traverse <= scrollLoc && traverse_up >= scrollLoc ) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
    })
  })

});
```

```css
.active {
  color: gray;
}

ul {
  position: fixed;
  background:#fff;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#first">About Me</a></li>
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#second">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#third">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="home" style="height:200px; background-color:red;"></div>
<div class="about-me" id="first" style="height:1000px; background-color:green;"></div>
<div class="portfolio" id="second" style="height:800px; background-color:blue;"></div>
<div class="contact" id="third" style="height:900px; background-color:orange;"></div>
```

Comment: yes i was working with condition that i think will take me 2-3days before figuring it out. this is the solution!!. thanks!! you have awesome logic!

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want to change the following code

```
if (traverse <= scrollLoc){
   $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).removeClass('active');
}
```

into something like this:

```
if (traverse <= scrollLoc){
   $(this).addClass('active');
} else { 
    $(this).removeClass('active');
}
```

Comment: yes i did forget to put an else statement. this did the trick somehow but not what i expect it to be. The classes are being added but i intend to apply the class on one anchor link only depending on where you are on the section of the page. thanks for the idea btw.